# Scrambled PHP code needs some fixing

Tags: php, decode, phpbb

I was adding a modification for my phpBB3 discussion board and one of the steps was to add a line of code to includes/functions.php

So when I copied that file and opened in wordpad I saw that it looked all scrambled. Here is how it looks partly:

```
<?php /** * * @package phpBB3 * @version $Id$ * @copyright (c) 2005 phpBB Group * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License * */  /** * @ignore */ if (!defined('IN_PHPBB')) {     exit; }  // Common global functions  /** * set_var * * Set variable, used by {@link request_var the request_var function} * * @access private */ function set_var(&$result, $var, $type, $multibyte = false) {  settype($var, $type);   $result = $var;     if ($type == 'string')  {       $result = trim(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\0"), array("\n", "\n", ''), $result), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));          if (!empty($result))        {           // Make sure multibyte characters are wellformed            if ($multibyte)             {               if (!preg_match('/^./u', $result))              {                   $result = '';               }           }           else            {               // no multibyte, allow only ASCII (0-127)               $result = preg_replace('/[\x80-\xFF]/', '?', $result);          }       }       $result = (STRIP) ? stripslashes($result) : $result;    } }  /** * request_var * * Used to get passed variable */ function request_var($var_name, $default, $multibyte = false, $cookie = false) {  if (!$cookie && isset($_COOKIE[$var_name]))     {       if (!isset($_GET[$var_name]) && !isset($_POST[$var_name]))      {           return (is_array($default)) ? array() : $default;       }       $_REQUEST[$var_name] = isset($_POST[$var_name]) ? $_POST[$var_name] : $_GET[$var_name];     }   $super_global = ($cookie) ? '_COOKIE' : '_REQUEST';     if (!isset($GLOBALS[$super_global][$var_name]) || is_array($GLOBALS[$super_global][$var_name]) != is_array($default))   {       return (is_array($default)) ? array() : $default;   }   $var = $GLOBALS[$super_global][$var_name];  if (!is_array($default))    {       $type = gettype($default);  }   else    {       list($key_type, $type) = each($default);        $type = gettype($type);         $key_type = gettype($key_type);         if ($type == 'array')       {           reset($default);            $default = current($default);           list($sub_key_type, $sub_type) = each($default);            $sub_type = gettype($sub_type);             $sub_type = ($sub_type == 'array') ? 'NULL' : $sub_type;            $sub_key_type = gettype($sub_key_type);         }   }   if (is_array($var))     {       $_var = $var;       $var = array();         foreach ($_var as $k => $v)         {           set_var($k, $k, $key_type);             if ($type == 'array' && is_array($v))           {               foreach ($v as $_k => $_v)              {                   if (is_array($_v))                  {                       $_v = null;                     }                   set_var($_k, $_k, $sub_key_type, $multibyte);                   set_var($var[$k][$_k], $_v, $sub_type, $multibyte);                 }           }           else            {               if ($type == 'array' || is_array($v))               {                   $v = null;              }               set_var($var[$k], $v, $type, $multibyte);           }       }   }   else    {       set_var($var, $var, $type, $multibyte);     }   return $var; }  /** * Set config value. Creates missing config entry. */ function set_config($config_name, $config_value, $is_dynamic = false) {    global $db, $cache, $config;    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . CONFIG_TABLE . "         SET config_value = '" . $db->sql_escape($config_value) . "'         WHERE config_name = '" . $db->sql_escape($config_name) . "'";   $db->sql_query($sql);   if (!$db->sql_affectedrows() && !isset($config[$config_name]))  {       $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . CONFIG_TABLE . ' ' . $db->sql_build_array('INSERT', array(          'config_name'   => $config_name,            'config_value'  => $config_value,           'is_dynamic'    => ($is_dynamic) ? 1 : 0));         $db->sql_query($sql);   }   $config[$config_name] = $config_value;      if (!$is_dynamic)   {       $cache->destroy('config');  } }  /** * Set dynamic config value with arithmetic operation. */ function set_config_count($config_name, $increment, $is_dynamic = false) {    global $db, $cache;     switch ($db->sql_layer)     {       case 'firebird':        case 'postgres':            $sql_update = 'CAST(CAST(config_value as DECIMAL(255, 0)) + ' . (int) $increment . ' as VARCHAR(255))';         break;          // MySQL, SQlite, mssql, mssql_odbc, oracle         default:            $sql_update = 'config_value + ' . (int) $increment;         break;  }   $db->sql_query('UPDATE ' . CONFIG_TABLE . ' SET config_value = ' . $sql_update . " WHERE config_name = '" . $db->sql_escape($config_name) . "'");   if (!$is_dynamic)   {       $cache->destroy('config');  } }  /** * Generates an alphanumeric random string of given length * * @return string */ function gen_rand_string($num_chars = 8) {     // [a, z] + [0, 9] = 36     return substr(strtoupper(base_convert(unique_id(), 16, 36)), 0, $num_chars); }  /** * Generates a user-friendly alphanumeric random string of given length * We remove 0 and O so users cannot confuse those in passwords etc. * * @return string */ function gen_rand_string_friendly($num_chars = 8) {    $rand_str = unique_id();    // Remove Z and Y from the base_convert(), replace 0 with Z and O with Y    // [a, z] + [0, 9] - {z, y} = [a, z] + [0, 9] - {0, o} = 34     $rand_str = str_replace(array('0', 'O'), array('Z', 'Y'), strtoupper(base_convert($rand_str, 16, 34)));     return substr($rand_str, 0, $num_chars); }  /** * Return unique id * @param string $extra additional entropy */ function unique_id($extra = 'c') {  static $dss_seeded = false;     global $config;     $val = $config['rand_seed'] . microtime();  $val = md5($val);   $config['rand_seed'] = md5($config['rand_seed'] . $val . $extra);   if ($dss_seeded !== true && ($config['rand_seed_last_update'] < time() - rand(1,10)))   {       set_config('rand_seed', $config['rand_seed'], true);        set_config('rand_seed_last_update', time(), true);      $dss_seeded = true;     }   return substr($val, 4, 16); }  /** * Return formatted string for filesizes * * @param int   $value          filesize in bytes * @param bool $string_only    true if language string should be returned * @param array   $allowed_units  only allow these units (data array indexes) * * @return mixed                   data array if $string_only is false * @author bantu */ function get_formatted_filesize($value, $string_only = true, $allowed_units = false) {   global $user;   $available_units = array(       'gb' => array(          'min'       => 1073741824, // pow(2, 30)            'index'     => 3,           'si_unit'   => 'GB',            'iec_unit'  => 'GIB',       ),      'mb' => array(          'min'       => 1048576, // pow(2, 20)           'index'     => 2,           'si_unit'   => 'MB',            'iec_unit'  => 'MIB',       ),      'kb' => array(          'min'       => 1024, // pow(2, 10)          'index'     => 1,           'si_unit'   => 'KB',            'iec_unit'  => 'KIB',       ),      'b' => array(           'min'       => 0,           'index'     => 0,           'si_unit'   => 'BYTES', // Language index           'iec_unit'  => 'BYTES',  // Language index      ),  );      foreach ($available_units as $si_identifier => $unit_info)  {       if (!empty($allowed_units) && $si_identifier != 'b' && !in_array($si_identifier, $allowed_units))       {           continue;       }       if ($value >= $unit_info['min'])        {           $unit_info['si_identifier'] = $si_identifier;           break;      }   }   unset($available_units);    for ($i = 0; $i < $unit_info['index']; $i++)    {       $value /= 1024;     }   $value = round($value, 2);      // Lookup units in language dictionary  $unit_info['si_unit'] = (isset($user->lang[$unit_info['si_unit']])) ? $user->lang[$unit_info['si_unit']] : $unit_info['si_unit'];   $unit_info['iec_unit'] = (isset($user->lang[$unit_info['iec_unit']])) ? $user->lang[$unit_info['iec_unit']] : $unit_info['iec_unit'];   // Default to IEC   $unit_info['unit'] = $unit_info['iec_unit'];    if (!$string_only)  {       $unit_info['value'] = $value;       return $unit_info;  }   return $value  . ' ' . $unit_info['unit']; }  /** * Determine whether we are approaching the maximum execution time. Should be called once * at the beginning of the script in which it's used. * @return   bool    Either true if the maximum execution time is nearly reached, or false *                 if some time is still left. */ function still_on_time($extra_time = 15) {   static $max_execution_time, $start_time;    $time = explode(' ', microtime());  $current_time = $time[0] + $time[1];    if (empty($max_execution_time))     {       $max_execution_time = (function_exists('ini_get')) ? (int) @ini_get('max_execution_time') : (int) @get_cfg_var('max_execution_time');       // If zero, then set to something higher to not let the user catch the ten seconds barrier.         if ($max_execution_time === 0)      {           $max_execution_time = 50 + $extra_time;         }       $max_execution_time = min(max(10, ($max_execution_time - $extra_time)), 50);        // For debugging purposes       // $max_execution_time = 10;        global $starttime;      $start_time = (empty($starttime)) ? $current_time : $starttime;     }   return (ceil($current_time - $start_time) < $max_execution_time) ? true : false; }  /** * * @version Version 0.1 / slightly modified for phpBB 3.0.x (using $H$ as hash type identifier) * * Portable PHP password hashing framework. * * Written by Solar Designer <solar at openwall.com> in 2004-2006 and placed in * the public domain. * * There's absolutely no warranty. * * The homepage URL for this framework is: * * http://www.openwall.com/phpass/ * * Please be sure to update the Version line if you edit this file in any way. * It is suggested that you leave the main version number intact, but indicate * your project name (after the slash) and add your own revision information. * * Please do not change the "private" password hashing method implemented in * here, thereby making your hashes incompatible.  However, if you must, please * change the hash type identifier (the "$P$") to something different. * * Obviously, since this code is in the public domain, the above are not * requirements (there can be none), but merely suggestions. * * * Hash the password */ function phpbb_hash($password) {     $itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';   $random_state = unique_id();    $random = '';   $count = 6;     if (($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')))   {       $random = fread($fh, $count);       fclose($fh);    }   if (strlen($random) < $count)   {       $random = '';       for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16)         {           $random_state = md5(unique_id() . $random_state);           $random .= pack('H*', md5($random_state));      }       $random = substr($random, 0, $count);   }   $hash = _hash_crypt_private($password, _hash_gensalt_private($random, $itoa64), $itoa64);   if (strlen($hash) == 34)    {       return $hash;   }   return md5($password); }  /** * Check for correct password * * @param string $password The password in plain text * @param string $hash The stored password hash * * @return bool Returns true if the password is correct, false if not. */ function phpbb_check_hash($password, $hash) {   $itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';   if (strlen($hash) == 34)    {       return (_hash_crypt_private($password, $hash, $itoa64) === $hash) ? true : false;   }   return (md5($password) === $hash) ? true : false; }  /** * Generate salt for hash generation */ function _hash_gensalt_private($input, &$itoa64, $iteration_count_log2 = 6) {   if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)    {       $iteration_count_log2 = 8;  }   $output = '$H$';    $output .= $itoa64[min($iteration_count_log2 + ((PHP_VERSION >= 5) ? 5 : 3), 30)];  $output .= _hash_encode64($input, 6, $itoa64);      return $output; }  /** * Encode hash */ function _hash_encode64($input, $count, &$itoa64) {     $output = '';   $i = 0;     do  {       $value = ord($input[$i++]);         $output .= $itoa64[$value & 0x3f];          if ($i < $count)        {           $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;         }       $output .= $itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];       if ($i++ >= $count)         {           break;      }       if ($i < $count)        {           $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;        }       $output .= $itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];          if ($i++ >= $count)         {           break;      }       $output .= $itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];  }   while ($i < $count);    return $output; }  /** * The crypt function/replacement */ function _hash_crypt_private($password, $setting, &$itoa64) {    $output = '*';      // Check for correct hash   if (substr($setting, 0, 3) != '$H$')    {       return $output;     }   $count_log2 = strpos($itoa64, $setting[3]);     if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)    {       return $output;     }   $count = 1 << $count_log2;  $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);     if (strlen($salt) != 8)     {       return $output;     }   /**     * We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only  * cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP  * currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto  * in PHP would result in much worse performance and     * consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are    * quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).   */  if (PHP_VERSION >= 5)   {       $hash = md5($salt . $password, true);       do      {           $hash = md5($hash . $password, true);       }       while (--$count);   }   else    {       $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));         do      {           $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));         }       while (--$count);   }   $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);  $output .= _hash_encode64($hash, 16, $itoa64);      return $output; }  /** * Hashes an email address to a big integer * * @param string $email      Email address * * @return string            Unsigned Big Integer */ function phpbb_email_hash($email) {     return sprintf('%u', crc32(strtolower($email))) . strlen($email); }  /** * Global function for chmodding directories and files for internal use * * This function determines owner and group whom the file belongs to and user and group of PHP and then set safest possible file permissions. * The function determines owner and group from common.php file and sets the same to the provided file. * The function uses bit fields to build the permissions. * The function sets the appropiate execute bit on directories. * * Supported constants representing bit fields are: * * CHMOD_ALL - all permissions (7) * CHMOD_READ - read permission (4) * CHMOD_WRITE - write permission (2) * CHMOD_EXECUTE - execute permission (1) * * NOTE: The function uses POSIX extension and fileowner()/filegroup() functions. If any of them is disabled, this function tries to build proper permissions, by calling is_readable() and is_writable() functions. * * @param string $filename   The file/directory to be chmodded * @param int  $perms      Permissions to set * * @return bool true on success, otherwise false * @author faw, phpBB Group */ function phpbb_chmod($filename, $perms = CHMOD_READ) {   static $_chmod_info;    // Return if the file no longer exists.     if (!file_exists($filename))    {       return false;   }   // Determine some common vars   if (empty($_chmod_info))    {       if (!function_exists('fileowner') || !function_exists('filegroup'))         {           // No need to further determine owner/group - it is unknown             $_chmod_info['process'] = false;        }       else        {           global $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx;            // Determine owner/group of common.php file and the filename we want to change here             $common_php_owner = @fileowner($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);          $common_php_group = @filegroup($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);              // And the owner and the groups PHP is running under.           $php_uid = (function_exists('posix_getuid')) ? @posix_getuid() : false;             $php_gids = (function_exists('posix_getgroups')) ? @posix_getgroups() : false;              // If we are unable to get owner/group, then do not try to set them by guessing             if (!$php_uid || empty($php_gids) || !$common_php_owner || !$common_php_group)          {               $_chmod_info['process'] = false;            }           else            {               $_chmod_info = array(                   'process'       => true,                    'common_owner'  => $common_php_owner,                   'common_group'  => $common_php_group,                   'php_uid'       => $php_uid,                    'php_gids'      => $php_gids,               );          }       }   }   if ($_chmod_info['process'])    {       $file_uid = @fileowner($filename);      $file_gid = @filegroup($filename);          // Change owner         if (@chown($filename, $_chmod_info['common_owner']))        {           clearstatcache();           $file_uid = @fileowner($filename);      }       // Change group         if (@chgrp($filename, $_chmod_info['common_group']))        {           clearstatcache();           $file_gid = @filegroup($filename);      }       // If the file_uid/gid now match the one from common.php we can process further, else we are not able to change something       if ($file_uid != $_chmod_info['common_owner'] || $file_gid != $_chmod_info['common_group'])         {           $_chmod_info['process'] = false;        }   }   // Still able to process?   if ($_chmod_info['process'])    {       if ($file_uid == $_chmod_info['php_uid'])       {           $php = 'owner';         }       else if (in_array($file_gid, $_chmod_info['php_gids']))         {           $php = 'group';         }       else        {           // Since we are setting the everyone bit anyway, no need to do expensive operations             $_chmod_info['process'] = false;        }   }   // We are not able to determine or change something     if (!$_chmod_info['process'])   {       $php = 'other';     }   // Owner always has read/write permission   $owner = CHMOD_READ | CHMOD_WRITE;  if (is_dir($filename))  {       $owner |= CHMOD_EXECUTE;        // Only add execute bit to the permission if the dir needs to be readable       if ($perms & CHMOD_READ)        {           $perms |= CHMOD_EXECUTE;        }   }   switch ($php)   {       case 'owner':           $result = @chmod($filename, ($owner << 6) + (0 << 3) + (0 << 0));           clearstatcache();           if (is_readable($filename) && phpbb_is_writable($filename))             {               break;          }       case 'group':           $result = @chmod($filename, ($owner << 6) + ($perms << 3) + (0 << 0));              clearstatcache();           if ((!($perms & CHMOD_READ) || is_readable($filename)) && (!($perms & CHMOD_WRITE) || phpbb_is_writable($filename)))            {               break;          }       case 'other':           $result = @chmod($filename, ($owner << 6) + ($perms << 3) + ($perms << 0));             clearstatcache();           if ((!($perms & CHMOD_READ) || is_readable($filename)) && (!($perms & CHMOD_WRITE) || phpbb_is_writable($filename)))            {               break;          }       default:            return false;       break;  }   return $result; }  /** * Test if a file/directory is writable * * This function calls the native is_writable() when not running under * Windows and it is not disabled. * * @param string $file Path to perform write test on * @return bool True when the path is writable, otherwise false. */ function phpbb_is_writable($file) {    if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'win' || !function_exists('is_writable'))  {       if (file_exists($file))         {           // Canonicalise path to absolute path           $file = phpbb_realpath($file);              if (is_dir($file))          {               // Test directory by creating a file inside the directory               $result = @tempnam($file, 'i_w');               if (is_string($result) && file_exists($result))                 {                   unlink($result);                    // Ensure the file is actually in the directory (returned realpathed)                   return (strpos($result, $file) === 0) ? true : false;               }           }           else            {               $handle = @fopen($file, 'r+');                  if (is_resource($handle))               {                   fclose($handle);                    return true;                }           }       }       else        {           // file does not exist test if we can write to the directory            $dir = dirname($file);              if (file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir) && phpbb_is_writable($dir))           {               return true;            }       }       return false;   }   else    {       return is_writable($file);  } }  // Compatibility functions  if (!function_exists('array_combine')) {   /**     * A wrapper for the PHP5 function array_combine()   * @param array $keys contains keys for the resulting array  * @param array $values contains values for the resulting array  *   * @return Returns an array by using the values from the keys array as keys and the  *   values from the values array as the corresponding values. Returns false if the  *   number of elements for each array isn't equal or if the arrays are empty.   */  function array_combine($keys, $values)  {       $keys = array_values($keys);        $values = array_values($values);        $n = sizeof($keys);         $m = sizeof($values);       if (!$n || !$m || ($n != $m))       {           return false;       }       $combined = array();        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)         {           $combined[$keys[$i]] = $values[$i];         }       return $combined;   } }  if (!function_exists('str_split')) {   /**     * A wrapper for the PHP5 function str_split()   * @param array $string contains the string to be converted  * @param array $split_length contains the length of each chunk  *   * @return  Converts a string to an array. If the optional split_length parameter is specified,  *   the returned array will be broken down into
```

As you can see all the new lines are cut so its just a big mess. I did still add the new code and it messed everything up. What can I do? Is there some type of script or anything that I can run this php file through that will fix lines? Note that I have no experience with PHP so please be detailed in your reply!

Comment: Additional note: I opened up the file in notepad++ and it was clear that the entire code was in one line. So all new lines are cut by some reason...?

Answer (score 1):

Both WordPad and Notepad++ handle UNIX-style newlines fine. I'm guessing that you or someone else previously opened and saved it with another program such as Notepad, which doesn't understand such newlines and probably messed it up. If you haven't modified the file so far, the simplest solution might be to get a fresh copy of this file from the phpBB3 archive.

Answer (score 0):

The file was probably created in *Nix, and uses the Unix newlines.  Wordpad likely can't handle those.

Try opening it up with a program that can handle the different types of newline styles, like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Hmm, you posted your comment between the time you posted the question, and I my answer...

Answer (score 0):

http://beta.phpformatter.com/

This will make your code look better.

Answer (score 0):

See the other solutions or try:

```
<?php

file_put_contents("source-fixed.php",
  str_replace("\n", "\r\n", file_get_contents("source.php")));

?>
```

Adjust the file names accordingly, of course.